# When I tried to compile my packages not all are compiled

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I want to install the `bb8` package from this link: [bb8-package-ros](https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/bb8/src/master/).

The steps that i made are:

1. Clone the git link on the directory `~/git`
2. Execute this command: `ln -s ~/git/bb8/ ~/catkin_ws/src/`
3. Go to rhe catkin directory: `cd ~/catkin_ws`
4. And compile the folder: `catkin_make`

At this point, i receive this error:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "robot_controllers"
  with any of the following names:

    robot_controllersConfig.cmake
    robot_controllers-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "robot_controllers" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "robot_controllers_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "robot_controllers" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'robot_controllers'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "robot_controllers"
  with any of the following names:

    robot_controllersConfig.cmake
    robot_controllers-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "robot_controllers" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "robot_controllers_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "robot_controllers" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

After I installed dependency: `sudo apt install ros-<distro>-robot-controllers` , I receive this error:

```
[ 97%] Built target turtlebot3_example_generate_messages
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgazebo_ros_utils
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/build.make:243: recipe for target '/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_bb_8_controller.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_bb_8_controller.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4777: recipe for target 'bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

I think I made all thinks good... But I don`t know why it give me this error.

Have somebody any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334247/when-i-tried-to-compile-my-packages-not-all-are-compiled/) by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is just a missing dependency.
Just do:

`sudo apt install ros-<distro>-robot-controllers`

This should fix it.

---

Originally posted by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) with karma: 196 on 2019-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-09-30**:
It give my anoother error:

```
[ 97%] Built target turtlebot3_example_generate_messages
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgazebo_ros_utils
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/build.make:243: recipe for target '/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_bb_8_controller.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_bb_8_controller.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4777: recipe for target 'bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [bb8/bb_8_gazebo/CMakeFiles/gazebo_bb_8_controller.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

**Comment by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on 2019-09-30**:
This is a completely different problem now. I had a look at the git repos and in my opinion (could be wrong) the problem is in the CMakeLists.txt file of the code on git, since no gazebo_ros_utils is either find package'd nor declared as a library.

What happens if you simply leave it away? Meaning to delete the "Gazebo_ros_utils" keyword from the CMakeLists?

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-09-30**:
You are great man! It works! Thanks a lot!